# Specify rows to read in from excel using pd.read_excel

Tags: excel, pandas

I have a large excel file and want to select specific rows (not continuous block) and columns to read in.  With columns this is easy, is there a way to do this for rows? or do I need to read in everything and then delete all the rows I don't want?

Consider an excel file with structure

```
,CW18r4_aer_7,,,,,,,
,Vegetation ,,,,,,,
Date,A1,A2,B1,B2,C1,C2,C3,C4
1/7/86,3.80,8.02,7.94,9.81,9.82,4.19,3.88,0.87
2/7/86,0.50,2.02,5.26,3.70,8.59,8.61,9.86,3.27
3/7/86,4.75,3.88,0.46,5.95,9.45,9.62,4.33,1.63
4/7/86,7.64,6.93,2.71,9.96,1.25,0.35,1.84,1.02
5/7/86,3.33,8.24,7.36,7.86,0.43,2.32,2.18,1.91
6/7/86,1.96,1.78,7.45,2.28,5.27,9.94,0.22,2.94
7/7/86,4.67,8.41,1.49,5.48,5.46,1.39,1.85,7.71
8/7/86,8.07,5.60,4.23,3.93,3.92,9.09,9.90,2.15
9/7/86,7.00,5.16,6.10,8.86,7.18,9.42,8.78,5.42
10/7/86,7.53,9.81,3.33,1.50,9.45,6.96,5.41,5.25
11/7/86,0.95,3.84,3.52,5.94,8.77,1.94,5.69,8.62
12/7/86,2.94,3.07,5.13,8.10,6.52,9.93,5.85,3.91
13/7/86,9.33,7.03,5.80,2.45,2.86,7.32,5.00,0.17
14/7/86,7.39,4.85,9.15,2.23,1.70,9.42,2.72,9.32
15/7/86,3.38,4.67,6.63,2.12,5.09,7.71,0.99,9.72
16/7/86,9.85,6.68,3.09,5.05,0.34,5.44,5.99,6.19
```

I want to take the headers from row 3 and then read in some of the rows and columns.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("filename.xlsx", skiprows = 2, usecols = "A:C,F:I", userows = "4:6,13,17:19")
```

Importantly, this is not a block that can be described by say [A3:C10] or the like.

The `userows` option does not exist.  I know I can skip rows at the top, and at the bottom - so presumably can make lots of data frames and knit them together.  But is there a simple way to just read in what you need once?  My workaround is to just create lots of excel spreadsheets that just have what I need for different data frames, but this leaves things very open to me making a mistake I can't find.

Comment: There's nothing built in to the `read_excel` function that does this, the best solution is probably to read in the whole thing, and then just take the rows you want with `.loc`.

Comment: Thanks @Jacob I suspected that was the case, but as I'm a novice user thought I should check.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a function to `skiprows` to mask the rows imported. In my example, I have to manually pass the column names because using `header` does something to `skiprows` that I don't understand. This works for trivial data.

```
In [1]: pd.read_excel(
   ...:     "data.xlsx",
   ...:     sheet_name="Sheet1",
   ...:     header=None,
   ...:     usecols="A:C,F:I",
   ...:     names=["Date", "A1", "A2", "C1", "C2", "C3", "C4"],
   ...:     skiprows=lambda x: x not in [4, 5, 6, 13, 17, 18, 19],
   ...: )
Out[2]:
  Date        A1    A2    C1    C2    C3    C4
0 1986-07-02  0.50  2.02  8.59  8.61  9.86  3.27
1 1986-07-03  4.75  3.88  9.45  9.62  4.33  1.63
2 1986-07-04  7.64  6.93  1.25  0.35  1.84  1.02
3 1986-07-11  0.95  3.84  8.77  1.94  5.69  8.62
4 1986-07-15  3.38  4.67  5.09  7.71  0.99  9.72
5 1986-07-16  9.85  6.68  0.34  5.44  5.99  6.19
```